# In teamcity, I have a batch of mstests running after the .sln file gets built. When the tests fail, I don't get emailed. Why?

Tags: teamcity

My email notifier in teamcity works well when the compilation fails. I have it set to notify me of failures and also the first success after the failure.

But when one test fails, I don't get an email. The build is set to fail when at least one test doesn't pass. I have nice red dot next to the build number.

The weird thing is, sometimes I get a success email after the test has been fixed, but not always. Does anyone know of any logs I can use to figure out why I'm not getting my email?

Here is another weird thing: I set the notifications to send me an email when the build fails and when the build succeeds. When the tests fail, I still get no email.

I do get notified properly in the windows try program, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm dumb, they were in my spam folder all along.

Answer (score 2):

There is teamcity-notification.log, especially useful if you enable DEBUG logging:
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Reporting+Issues#ReportingIssues-LoggingEvents

Are the rules for email and tray notifiers the same? If yes, most probably that is a transportation failure, the error must be in the log.

BTW there is TeamCity 7.0 RC1 available:
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/TeamCity+EAP

Comment: I've been through that log, and there's no error. There's nothing wrong with the emailer, it sends me emails most of the time. Thanks for notifying me of the TeamCity 7.0. Maybe I'll try it out.

Comment: Sorry for the delay (I wasn't notified of your comment =). Please try to enable DEBUG. If nothing is clear after it, please report the issue at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/ with all the details (screenshots, logs, etc). And yes, TC7 is out!

Comment: The fail emails mysteriously started arriving as soon as i had more than one test in the test list. But then one time after that the email didn't arrive. Most of the time they show up. It's not consistent. I should upgrade to TeamCity 7.0 now that it is released.